# How does WebRTC use libjingle?

Tags: libjingle, webrtc

I download WebRTC's source code, but I can't find any libjingle's code at the WebRTC, and can't find how WebRTC use libjingle (can't find such as XmppTask Class in WebRTC's code)

Can anyone give me a guide?

Answer (score 20):

Libjingle is now part of the WebRTC project and code base.  WebRTC is a set of API's that make video, audio, and data interaction simple through a peer-to-peer connection.  Where as Libjingle is used as a part of the WebRTC implementation to handle NAT traversal and stream handling.

Libjingle was initially used solely through XMPP to create a point-to-point connection between two chat clients.  The technologies used are ICE, STUN, and TURN.

WebRTC has a large focus on Javascript mainly because its core usefulness is using the functionality through a browser.  However, WebRTC (with Libjingle), can be built for many platforms and has a number of different APIs in various languages.

Libjingle is written in C++, so can be used by itself without WebRTC. However, I recommend using Libjingle's functionality through the way of the WebRTC APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, libjingle folder in webrtc has been removed in the lastest version. You can ignore it.

Comment: What does this mean? What replaces libjingle?

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate packages.

WebRTC is the multimedia part only - nothing to do with signaling (which is what XMPP and Jingle are).

libjingle is used to build an application that runs on a device or a PC while WebRTC is designed and targeted at being integrated into HTML pages using a web browser.

Comment: The two aren't mutually exclusive, as I have answered below.  There are non-javascript APIs for WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC - audio/video/data transfer p2p.
Signalling - establishes connection between 2 WebRTC based apps.
Take a look over this android [webrtc videocall app](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC/blob/android-studio/webrtc-client/src/main/java/fr/pchab/webrtcclient/WebRtcClient.java) and this [nodejs signalling relay](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster).
You send a 'message' (check in file `sockets.js` in relay project at the following line

```
`client.on('message', function (details) {`
```

to see what's happening with it) of type 'init' from device A to device B, then device B creates an offer to device A. After that A answers to B, exchanging Ice Candidates then video connection is ready. (I'm sorry if i wasn't very explicit).